# 2d game engine for race game built to web-page

Tags: apache-flex, flash, game-engine

I think Flash/Flex is a good aproach for this case.
We need to build some like the following:
http://www.flashracegames.com/play-micro-racers-2.html

Is there some free engines to perform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is definitely the tool for the job. I'd try the [box2d](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/) engine to handle all the physics and collisions. It's a port from the great box2d c++ library, and it can do great stuff and help with the performance (always a concern in flash). The only quirk is that you'll need to turn off gravity and damping in order to account for the top-down view. Check [this tutorial](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/) to see how to build a top-down car in box2d as a start.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [pushbutton engine](http://pushbuttonengine.com/). It has a fair amount of nice features and should get you up and running faster than starting from scratch...

I would definitely recommend sticking with Flash and not using Flex for this one...too much overhead for features you probably wouldn't need...